# Is $\mathrm{SO}(2)$ a subgroup of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$?

Tags: group-theory

I am learning quantum mechanics. I can’t find any connection between $\mathrm{SO}$ and $\mathrm{SU}$ from the Internet. On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group#The_group_SU(2)), $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ is defined by

$$
\operatorname {SU} (2)=\left\{{\begin{pmatrix}\alpha &-{\overline {\beta }}\\\beta &{\overline {\alpha }}\end{pmatrix}}:\ \ \alpha ,\beta \in \mathbb {C} ,|\alpha |^{2}+|\beta |^{2}=1\right\}~.
$$

And from the [Wikipedia page about $\mathrm{SO}(2)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_group#Isomorphisms), I saw

$$
e^{i\theta }\leftrightarrow {\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta &-\sin \theta \\\sin \theta &\cos \theta \\\end{bmatrix}}=f\left(e^{i\theta }\right).
$$

If I set $\alpha = \cos\theta$ and $\beta = \sin\theta$ to the definition of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$, it will become $\mathrm{SO}(2)$. Can I say $\mathrm{SO}(2)$ is a subgroup of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A \in SO(2)$, then since $a=\bar{a}$ when $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sin(\theta)^2+\cos(\theta)^2=1$ we see that $A \in SU(2)$. Hence $SO(2) \subset SU(2)$. Since we know that $SO(2)$ is already a group we see the closure, inverse, and identity axioms for a subgroup are satisfied. Thus $SO(2)$ is a subgroup of $SU(2)$.

Answer (score 1):

$SO(2)$ (angle) is isomorphic to $U(1)$ (unit circle) and can be embedded in $SU(2).$ However, I wouldn't call it a subgroup. The embedding is neither natural nor canonical. Orthogonal refers to something real, unitary to something complex. Here is a list of possible identifications of orthogonal groups, and their quotients to spheres:
https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/journey-manifold-su2mathbbc-part/

Comment: Why isn't it a subgroup? It's just the elements of $SU(2)$ with no I'm imaginary parts.

Comment: It is embedded, i.e. there is a monomorphism $SO(2,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow SU(2,\mathbb{C}).$ I didn't say it cannot be called a subgroup, I said "However, I wouldn't call it a subgroup. The embedding is neither natural nor canonical." Subgroup is a word that sets you on the wrong track.

Comment: I see where you are going and it's a fair point. However from the strictly mathematical point of view it does satisfy the definition of a subgroup which was the original question. I'll leave it to the poster to decided how they want to think about it.

Comment: One could phrase it like this: It is a good idea to call it a subgroup if you want to win a bet, but a bad idea if you want to do physics, especially QM.